# "Would it be okay for you" | Verb tense past or present

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

As a non-native speaker, I wonder which, if any, of the following would be correct:

> Would it be okay for you if I **attached** the document?
>
> Would it be okay for you if I **attach** the document?

The inquiry is about the future, so I have not attached any documents by now.

Comment: Which might be better would depend on the entire time frame involving the document and to what it might be attached. If there is  a series of events, the timing of those events is critical to the tense of verbs used..

Comment: *attached* shows (more) deference. *okay for you* is not natural; use *all right with you*.

Comment: Use _okay **with** you_ and either _attach/ed_ form.